# Applications I download stay in Downloads, unlike software installed via APT. How do I correctly install downloaded applications?

Tags: software-installation

I'm having some troubles installing applications, e.g. jdk, anaconda, IDE and everything else in my Ubuntu.

After I download these programs from the website in `tar.gz` format, when I extract these files, they are still in the `Downloads` directory.

Some of the files downloaded from Ubuntu Software or `apt-get` are automatically installed and well distributed in directories owned by root, not my user, e.g. npm downloaded from `apt-get` is in `/usr/bin/`.

But if I download just like in Windows, directly through the official site (like Oracle, JetBrains, Anaconda) they remain in the `Downloads` directory even after I extract and install.

How can I download applications on system-level (or root-level, not user) and make them properly-distributed?

Comment: "just like in Windows" is key to the problem. Ubuntu is not Windows, and The Windows way is not the 'right' way...though it's understandable that you may be used to it. What you have described seems like expected behavior. A .tar.gz file is not an installer like an .msi. Tarballs are like .zips, a compressed bunch of files  lacking any location, install, or uninstall information.

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate especially [Advice for users coming from Windows](https://askubuntu.com/a/575161/527764)  I.E. Don't download and install applications unless someone gives you specific instructions on how and why to do so...

Answer (score 0):

For me, I look on the official websites or Github repositories to see if they offer any installation instructions. Most times they do.

I've found that most of the ones which come in archive folders as you'd described seem to run directly (such as FreeFileSync) so it's just a matter of finding somewhere neat to store it.

I'm not sure if this is the 'correct' way, but for me I look for the /opt folder of my system and drop those types of ones into there. (NOTE: This would need to be done via the terminal because /opt is only available to root by default.)

Hope that helps, and I hope I'm not leading you astray!